# How to store the credentials of a VSAM password file in COBOL?

Tags: cobol, zos, vsam, racf

This is the code which [IBM official page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS6SG3_4.2.0/com.ibm.entcobol.doc_4.2/PGandLR/ref/rpvsm35e.htm) recommends to handle a VSAM password protected file:

```
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT LIBFILE
      ASSIGN TO PAYMAST
      ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
      RECORD KEY IS EMPL-NUM
         PASSWORD IS BASE-PASS
      ALTERNATE RECORD KEY IS EMPL-PHONE
         PASSWORD IS PATH1-PASS
. . .
WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01  BASE-PASS          PIC X(8) VALUE "25BSREAD".
01  PATH1-PASS         PIC X(8) VALUE "25ATREAD".
```

But as you can see, the password is in plain text. What is the most elegant way to store this kind of credentials in zOS so I can access from a COBOL program?

Comment: As cschneid say's use the **Security Manager**. Typically all security measures are controlled by a single group in ZOS. File based security died a long time ago (1970's ???) on ZOS. Even in the 1980's it was not used where I worked.

Comment: A simple obfuscation could be rot13, but, yeah, seriously, use SAF security. Passwords are seriously 1970s. There’s only one reason these days for a password in SYS1.UADS (TSO) and that’s for a 1- or 2-pack rescue IPL volume

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this.  Use your External Security Manager (probably ACF2, RACF, or Top Secret) instead.  Talk to your shop's security people.